My phone has been reset using find my device, is it illegal? how do i disable it?
Posted on Google by me, Nov 9, 2024
Urgent: Account Security Issue
My employees informed me that the main animator's phone (Infinix) was used to reset all devices connected to our shared account via 'Find my device'. This includes:

My phone
All other devices
Authenticator (now reset)
Microsoft work account (MS Auth) access

I share this account with employees for YouTube access. How can I disable 'Find my device' to prevent further unwanted resets?
Please help me resolve this issue ASAP

Having a shared account is asking for this things to happen.

Note that this community can't answer legal question.
